# программа вылетает

Tags: c

Я пишу программу, где нужно исправить фразы начинающиеся с большой буквы.

У меня возникла такая загвоздка: после ввода количества строк программа вылетает. Консоль никаких ошибок не выдает. В чем может быть причина ошибки?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 256

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n;
    int caps = 0;
    printf("Введите количество абзацев: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    char str[n][10*N];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        gets(str[i]);
        for (int k = 0; k < strlen(str[i]) - 2; k++) {
            if ((str[i][k] != '.' || str[i][k] != '!' || str[i][k] != '?') && str[i][k + 1] == ' ' && isalpha(str[i][k + 2]) && isupper(str[i][k + 2])) {
                str[i][k + 2] = tolower(str[i][k + 2]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) puts(str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какое примерно `n` вы вводите? Может, в стеке места не хватает на `str[n][2560]`? Хотя вряд ли... И еще - безотносительно к ошибке, *никогда* не используйте `gets`!

Comment: n ввожу самое тестовое - 1.

Comment: и насчет gets. что предлагаете использовать вместо него в этом случае?

Comment: @PrometheusMusic, вместо `gets ()`, стандартное — `fgets(str, max_str_size, stdin)`. Из последнего стандарта `gets ()` наконец-то удалена. По ошибке — после `scanf ()` в буфере ввода остаётся конец строки, который и считывает `gets ()`, после чего программа корректно (скорее всего) завершается.

Comment: это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: попробовал сделать все это через getchar() , но не работает

Comment: все, исправил.
немного сменил ввод 
`while ((g = getc(stdin) != EOF) && g !='\n') {
fgets(str[n], 10*N, stdin);
...;
n++;
}`

Comment: спасибо за правильное направление мысли

Comment: Вы сами-то поняли, что за условие Вы написали? :-) Смотрите, вот кусочек Вашего условия:  *str[i][k] != '.' || str[i][k] != '!'*. При ЛЮБОМ значении *str[i][k]*, это значение никак не может быть и точкой и восклицательным знаком ОДНОВРЕМЕННО.  Значит, либо оба, либо одно из условий всегда буде истинным. Поскольку условия объединяются по "или", то полное условие будет истинным ВСЕГДА.

Comment: ??? не понял суть проблемы. тут же логическое ИЛИ, а не логическое И. почему они должны быть одновременно не равны и тому, и тому? символ не равен или точке, или восклицательному знаку

Comment: в общем, я применил ваше замечание после неудачной работы программы. написал функцию для проверки вхождения символа в массив. не знаю, может проще было написать что-то типа `a in [b, c, d]`, но я не знаю, работает ли в С это. поэтому я написал функцию